# Angular 4 DataTables. Search placeholder

Tags: html, angular, datatables

I have DataTables loaded into my Angular app and was wondering how I can put some text in the search box as a placholder. Also I want the word "Search:" to appear to the left of the box, which I thought was the default but I guess not. Here's what I have plus a screenshot.

**component.ts**

```
dtOptions: any = {
  lengthChange: false,
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'colvis'
  ],
  aoColumnDefs: [
    { aTargets: [7, 8], bVisible: false}
  ]
};
dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

**component.html**

```
 <table datatable class="bordered" [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

**In .ts file**

---

```
export class WithOptionsComponent implements OnInit {

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
     searchPlaceholder: 'search here',
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 export class WithOptionsComponent implements OnInit {

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
     language: {
        searchPlaceholder: 'Search user',
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add language property to set the wording.

**component.ts**

```
dtOptions: any = {
  lengthChange: false,
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'colvis'
  ],
  aoColumnDefs: [
    { aTargets: [7, 8], bVisible: false}
  ],
  language: {
    url: '/assets/styles/en.json',
    searchPlaceholder: "Search here...",
    search: "Search:",
  }
};
```